# how to remove lubuntu and install ubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, uninstall

I recently purchased a Thinkpad R40 with Lubuntu on it but don't have the install cd's. The person I got it from doesn't know the administrator password so I can't access any changes. I went to the root screen thinking maybe I could change the password that way but it keeps telling me Give root password for maintenance (or type Control-D to continue). I was hoping to uninstall Lubuntu and install Ubuntu but don't know the steps for this. Can anyone please help me? I am new to Linux and don't want to mess anything up.

Answer (score 1):

You can just install ubuntu, the old installation will be erased when you chose the option use entire disk during the installation setup. You can download the iso of ubuntu 12.10 from here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download

Or 12.04.1 LTS, you might prefer 12.04.1 because it's an LTS which means is's supported for five years instead of one and a half years for a normal release:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/ .

Burn the iso on a dvd, boot from it and install.

If you're going to dual boot with windows don't follow my instructions because you'll erase windows too. You can find dual boot instructions here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot .

It might be a good idea though to install lubuntu 12.10 because you're machine is a bit older, it might be sluggish when you install regular ubuntu. You can obtain the lubuntu iso here:

http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.10/release/

Lubuntu 12.04 is not an LTS so I'd get lubuntu 12.10.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will burn the iso and download it tonight. I am not running windows on it I have a seperate computer for that.